Does a pure C program need to follow the part of ABI about proper prologue or .xdata when compiled on Win64?
Let's say, if I don't care exceptions -- I will neither throw nor catch a exception, or need I exceptions pass through the pure C stack. Then do I need to care the xdata or SEH things?
That is, are completely custom ABI allowed at all on Win64? Need I align the stack pointer to 16 bits if I don't use movaps or call into functions that may assume aligned stack?
Will (for example) page faulst come and cause problems?
Or need I touch the stack if stack frame is bigger than 4096?
